# How could I deploy a tabpy code when I already have an API endpoint running using django in an virtual environment?

Tags: python

I am trying to create an api endpoint using django in python and restrserve in R and deploying the below code in tabpy to connect with tableau and I am facing with this error.Could someone recommend on any solution.

Error message:

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9004): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /endpoints (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000016136C007C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))

Code:

```
import tabpy_client
import requests
client = tabpy_client.Client('http://127.0.0.1:9004')

def external_services_say_hello(message, service):
    if service == 'PYTHON':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', data ={'message': message})
    elif service == 'R':
        r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/hello', data = {'message': message,})
 
    serviceResult = r.json()
    return serviceResult['result']

client.deploy('external_services_say_hello', external_services_say_hello, 'Make Python or R say Hello or anything you want.', override = True)
print('*** Model deployed successfully ***')
```

Thanks in advance!